# Where can I find the list of all updates released by Google for Nexus devices?

Tags: updates, ota-update

it's been a while since I updated my Nexus 10 tablet and with each new update, I'm being notified of further newer updates. I've updated my device 6-7 times in 3 days. Where can I find the list of all released updates so I can decide whether I want to update to get certain feature in a later update or not?

Comment: Don't worry, Nexus 10 is EOL long ago. Finishing your current batch of upgrades will only catch you up to the last one available... back in April 2016. Any newer patch you see on the security bulletin you found *won't* be available for your device (unless you decide to dive into the world of custom ROMs, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In the link below they have the factory images for all the versions of Androids for Nexus and Pixel devices

https://developers.google.com/android/images

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I found that there's a list of all security updates here:

https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/

Edit: will update if I find the list for each device.

Comment: It has been found by an another user. Here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176221/96277